# Jupyter notebook 'greedy completer' configuration

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have the following 'magic' command for Jupyter iPython notebook:

```
%config IPCompleter.greedy=True
```

However I don't know where I could put in in a configuration file to have it by default on each newly opened notebook.

Should it go `.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is IPython configuration, so it should go in `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`.

Jupyter configuration only affects frontend applications providing UI (e.g. notebook server, qtconsole, etc.), not the kernels (IPython, IJulia, etc.) which may have their own configuration mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` you can create it using this command in the terminal

```
$ ipython profile create
```

Open this file and search for `greedy` and remove the comment of this configuration and change False to True.

```
c.Completer.greedy = True
```

Enter the following commands to the terminal to install an unofficial extension `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` and enable more features in your notebook without using `tab` or `shift+tab`.

```
$ pip3 install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
$ jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

In your notebook go to `Edit > nbextensions config` and enable `Hinterland`. Now code autocompletion menu for every keypress in a code cell, instead of only calling it with `tab` is enabled.