# Is there a docstring autocompletion tool for jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, docstring

I am looking for a tool/extension that helps you writing python docstrings in jupyter notebook.

I normally use VS code where you have the [autodocstring](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njpwerner.autodocstring) extension that automatically generates templates (e.g. the sphinx or numpy template) for docstrings.  Is there an equivalent to this in jupyter notebook?

I have been looking online for a long time now, but have trouble finding it.

Answer (score 1):

run this in a Notebook cell:

```
%config IPCompleter.greedy=True
```

Then press tab where you want to do autocomplete.

(Extracted from [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/5k6cv8/pythonjupyter_notebookhow_to_enable_autocomplete/))

Answer (score 0):

To make use of auto complete **without** the use of `tab` or `shift+tab` follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66938657/12249400).
However, I do not think there is an autodocstring extension for jupyter notebook like the one on VS Code you mentioned.