# Jupyter Notebook Python auto docstring generation with triple quotation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, documentation, jupyter, documentation-generation

I'm working in a jupyter notebook using python and trying to use the auto-documentation function to generate docstrings like below. When working in an IDE like pycharm a **triple quotation +  Enter** underneath the function generates docstrings like shown below.

```
def test_function(df: pd.DataFrame, probs: dict) -> int:
    """
    :param df: 
    :param probs: 
    :return: 
    """
```

Currently my output from the notebook gives the output below and does not parse any arguments inside the function.

```
def test_function(df: pd.DataFrame, probs: dict) -> int:
    """

    """
```

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54594779/is-there-a-docstring-autocompletion-tool-for-jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 1):

You can have that functionality in VScode, sublime, pytorch and other IDEs but not in jupyter the closest solution I found was to install  **nbextensions** and use **snippets** to add a docstring template. it decreases typing by 50% but still not auto generating.

Comment: pytorch is an IDE ? Do you mean PyCharm ?